# Show DU outcome in purely megabytes

Tags: linux, bash, redhat, du

I am using `DU` function to output the directory size to a file and then move it to an excel file to add the total. Is it possible to output the size of a directory only in MB (even if the size is in KB or GB):

e.g. if the file size is 50kb the output would show 0.048MB

I'm aware of `du -h` however I haven't been able to maintain the size in MBs if the size is larger than 1024, since it's switches to 1G.
The `du -m` however does not show the M (for megabytes) next to the value so isn't really human friendly.

Thanks in advance,
J

Comment: Thanks @BrettHale, I've tried that however it does not show the M next to the figure. Is there a combination of -m and -h which shows the values of M and makes it more human friendly ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's the `-m` option. So, for example:

```
$ du -s -m <my_directory_here>
```

**UPDATE**

Oh... you want an "M" printed after the number of megabytes. Here you are:

```
$ du -s -m /usr/local | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)\(.*\)$/\1M \2/'
```

or...

```
$ du -s -m /usr/local | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)\(.*\)$/\1MiB \2/'
```

or...

```
$ du -s -m /usr/local | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)\(.*\)$/\1 MegaBytes \2/'
```

etc.

**UPDATE2**

If you want fractions I would use `du -k` to print KiB and then:

```
$ du -s -k * | awk '{printf "%.3f MiB %s\n", $1/1024, $2}'
43.355 MiB bin
0.008 MiB etc
0.562 MiB include
5.836 MiB lib
0.008 MiB man
0.004 MiB mysql
2259.738 MiB mysql-5.5.27-osx10.6-x86_64
45.711 MiB share
340.641 MiB texlive
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've tried that aswell however it does not show the outcome with an M. Is there a combination of -m and -h which shows the values of M and makes it more human friendly ?

Comment: Thanks for your update. This way values smaller than 1 MB are rounded to 1 MB. Is there a way to also show values less than 1M in point version, eg. 0.50 M

Comment: Thanks @mauro. Very helpful

Comment: I really like your "Update2" style, like this: `du -sk path/to/my/file | awk '{printf "%.3f MiB %s\n", $1/1024, $2}'`. It works very well and looks very nice. I like seeing the fractional part of the Mebibytes.